# how to find a sequential sub array which has the biggest sum within O(n)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Given a number array, including positive and negative numbers, the question is to find a **sequential sub array** which has the biggest sum and the time complexity is O(n), for example, [1,-2,3,10,-4,7,2,-5] is an array, and the sub array [3, 10, -4, 7, 2] has the biggest sum which is 18. 
So how to find this sub array within O(n)?
Thx

Comment: [Kadane's algorithm for the maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wiki [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane.27s_algorithm) to this solution. Its called Maximum subarray sum problem. Solution is provided by Kadane which runs in O(n) time.

Comment: thx very much. Also thank the others.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in Python. The idea is to search the maximum consecutive sum. When that sum is negative, you empty the list, if it's not negative, then you must keep those elements.

```
l =  [1,-2,3,10,-4,7,2,-5]

def find_max(l):
    s = 0 # Current sum
    lsum = [] # Current subarray
    res = (0, []) # Max value and subarray

    for v in l:
       s += v
       lsum.append(v)
       if s > res[0]:
         res = (s, lsum[:])
       elif s < 0:
         s = 0
         lsum = []

    return res

print find_max(l)
```

Result:

```
(18, [3, 10, -4, 7, 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is look at the cumulative series (treat the values as increment/decrements of something) and then find the low and subsequent high of this series.

In pseudo code:

```
sum = 0
low = Integer.MaxValue
highestSumSinceLow = Integer.MinValue
For i = 0 to Array.Length-1
  sum += Array[i]                            // keep track of cumulative value since start
  If sum < low Then                          
    low = sum                                // keep track of lowest sum since start so far
    substart = i + 1                         //    and set substart to next value
  sumsincelow = sum - low                    // calculate sum from that low to here
  If sumsincelow > highestSumSinceLow Then   
    highestSumSinceLow = sumsincelow         // keep track of highest sumsincelow
    subend = i                               //    and set subend to this value
Next i
```

After going through the entire array, `substart` and `subend` point to the indices of the sub array with the highest sum (which is `highestSumSinceLow`).

This is probably the simplest and most efficient solution. It is O(n) and doesn't use temporary arrays. It just goes through the array once from start to finish and keeps track of the lowest cumulative sum since start and the highest sum since that low.